# Uniqueness of Riesz representation theory

Tags: real-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

I am trying to prove the uniqueness of the Riesz representation theory for the real analysis context. The question statement is

> Given $\alpha\in BV[a,b]$, show that there is a unique $\beta\in BV[a, b]$ with $\beta(a) = 0$ such that $\beta$ is right-continuous on $(a, b)$ and $\int_a^bfd\alpha = \int_a^bfd\beta$ for every $f\in C[a,b]$.

The integral here are Riemann-Stieltjes inegrals. I have no idea how to approach this problem. Many thanks to any help.

Comment: Hint: Let $a<t<b$ and take $f(x)=1$ for $x<t, 0$ for $x \geq t$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks for the hint, but f is not continuous here.

Comment: Approximate my $f$ by a continuous function  and use right -continuityof $\beta$.